# Bootstrap Show and Hide a id with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that I want to show if the user make click in a checkbox (yes) and hide if make click in other checkbox (no)

I need some javascript or jquery code to show and hide the div with id "test" depend of the selection of the user in the checkboxs (yes or no)

```
<div class="row" id="test">
        //div that I want show/hide
</div>


//I have this two checkbox yes__ no__
```

Yes 

     No

Comment: What is your question? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the checked for this and do something like so

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + div {diplay: block;}
```

here is an exmple I made for you :

**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwJwdm)**

HTML :

```
<div style="clear:both;">
<input type="checkbox" id="test1ck"> <div class="lool" >Check and Uncheck Me</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="test2ck"> <div class="lool" >Check and uncheck me too!</div></div>
```

CSS :

```
.lool {
  display: none;
}


input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.lool {
  display:block;
  color: red;
}
```

of course make sure your are not trying to select a parent element, there is no way to select a parent with CSS only

Comment: if better to put this code in onClick event of the checkbox or apart in javascript tag?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I'm aware of is to add AngularJS and angular-animate to your project (see below).  You can then use simple directives to do what you want, and AngularJS does all the "heavy lifting" for you in JavaScript.  This doesn't require any custom javascript or css.  I included Bootstrap for some extra styling, but it isn't necessary for what you want.

NOTE:  There may be a way to do this with checkboxes, but radio buttons were easier to toggle between.  If you wanted to use a single checkbox, checked for "yes" and unchecked for "no", the HTML markup would be even simpler.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Example - example-example92-production</title>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
<div>
  Yes: <input type="radio" id="test1ck" ng-click="yesIsChecked = true" value="y" ng-model="checked">
  <br/>
  No: <input type="radio" id="test2ck" ng-click="yesIsChecked = false" value="n" ng-model="checked">
  <br/>
  <div ng-show="yesIsChecked">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> I show up when your checkbox is checked.
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```